# How can I get an array from a comma separated string in Java

Tags: java

I have a string:

```
String accounts = "Account 1, Account 2, Account 3"
```

That I would like to convert into an array ie something along the lines of ["Account 1" , "Account 2", "Account 3"].

What is the easiest way of doing this in Java?

Comment: Try googling for 'splitting' a String in stead of 'converting' it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [String.split(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String accounts = "Account 1, Account 2, Account 3"
String[] arr = accounts.split(",");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String accounts = "Account 1, Account 2, Account 3";
String[] parts = accounts.split(", ");
String part1 = parts[0]; // Account 1
String part2 = parts[1]; // Account 2
```

Answer (score 2):

use split: `accounts.split(",")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#split` -

```
String accounts = "Account 1, Account 2, Account 3";
String[] accs = accounts.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use built in String method:

```
String[] result = accounts.split(",");
```

To get rid of spaces add space into split argument:

```
String[] result = accounts.split(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the leading whtie space between the tokens.

```
String accounts = "Account 1, Account 2, Account 3";
String[] tokens = accounts.split(", ");
```

Comment: Why not just `accounts.split(", ")`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

EDIT:

```
String str = "st1-st2-st3";
String delimiter = "-";
String[] temp;
temp = str.split(delimiter);
```

For more info: 
http://www.wikihow.com/Split-String-in-Java

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
String accounts = "Account 1, Account 2, Account 3";
String[] array = accounts.split(",");
```

Comment: No you can't, that will give you a syntax error. Should be regular, not square, brackets for the method call.

Answer (score 0):

```
accounts.split("\\,");
```

Any examples you can find at [this page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will handle (i.e. remove) any amount of whitespace before or after the comma, so there will be no whitespace before or after the text for each element in the resulting array.

```
accounts.split(" *, *");
```